# caAndroid+applicaiton crash when open for SMS/MMS in samsung galaxy s3

Tags: android, android-intent

Application get crashed when i try to open the SMS/MMS

This code works for rest for all the device.But only causing crash for samsung galxy s3 version 4.2
**Code:-**

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
  sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
    "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");

  sendIntent.putExtra("subject", "subject");
  sendIntent
    .putExtra(
      "sms_body",
      "body");
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, musicURI);
  sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
  startActivity(sendIntent);
```

The Carsh Trak:-

```
Log Collector version: 1.2.0
Device model: GT-I9300
Firmware version: 4.0.4
Kernel version: 3.0.15-928452
se.infra@SEP-70 )
#1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 21 17:04:13 KST 2012
Build number: IMM76D.I9300XXBLH3

12-20 01:42:25.120 D/CustomFrequencyManagerService( 2095): releaseGPU -> count of GPU locks :0
12-20 01:42:25.120 D/CustomFrequencyManagerService( 2095): ### revertGPUToDefault : 0
12-20 01:42:25.255 D/dalvikvm( 4153): GC_CONCURRENT freed 235K, 9% free 14771K/16199K, paused 1ms+2ms
12-20 01:42:25.490 I/InputReader( 2095): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0, s=0.6392 ]
12-20 01:42:25.490 I/InputDispatcher( 2095): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
12-20 01:42:25.490 I/InputDispatcher( 2095): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
12-20 01:42:25.490 I/InputDispatcher( 2095): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
12-20 01:42:25.555 I/InputReader( 2095): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0, s=]
12-20 01:42:25.555 I/InputDispatcher( 2095): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
12-20 01:42:25.555 I/InputDispatcher( 2095): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
12-20 01:42:25.555 I/InputDispatcher( 2095): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
12-20 01:42:25.705 V/Mms/ConversationListFragment( 3863): onSweepActionCanceled(),itemIndex=0
12-20 01:42:25.705 D/Mms/ConversationListFragment( 3863): onListItemClick(),position=0, id=154
12-20 01:42:25.705 D/Mms/Conversation( 3863): get(Context,long,boolean),threadId=154,allowQueryfalse
12-20 01:42:25.705 D/Mms/ConversationListFragment( 3863): isSearchMode() : false
12-20 01:42:25.705 D/Mms/Conversation( 3863): get(Context,long,boolean),threadId=154,allowQueryfalse
12-20 01:42:25.705 D/Mms/ConversationListFragment( 3863): openThread startActivity for threadId 154 , CMAS= false , isPresidential = false
12-20 01:42:25.705 E/Mms/Conversa from my HTC
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the stack trace you get on the crash.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...I wrote the crash log which we got from the device